# No conduit initiator found for namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http

Tags: http, cxf, conduit

We are using apache cxf 2.6.1 to call Restful API. Both Server and the client use cxf libraries. On the client side, we use cxf generated client. Everything works in dev environment but we recently saw this error in production environment. I googled and found nothing for this specific namespace. I am wondering if anybody else got this. I already verified that the class path has following 5 cxf libraries (both in dev and prod). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**List of cxf jars we have in class path:**

```
/opt/mhs/lib/cxf-api-2.6.1.jar
/opt/mhs/lib/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.6.1.jar
/opt/mhs/lib/cxf-rt-core-2.6.1.jar
/opt/mhs/lib/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.1.jar
/opt/mhs/lib/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.1.jar
```

**Here is the error message. Its very generic and I am having hard time finding the root cause.**

```
apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://rest.perfmon.kiva.com/}IPerfMonRestEntityAssociationService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No conduit initiator was found for the namespace http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http.
at     org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:127)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.selectConduit(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.message.ExchangeImpl.getConduit(ExchangeImpl.java:130)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.getConduit(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:71)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:46)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:526)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:205)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.addEntityAssociation(Unknown Source)
```